# How can I make my local Git repository accessible for multiple users?

Tags: git, permissions, file-permissions

I want to create a git repository and allow all users to have access to it. I tried initializing it by:

```
git init --shared=all
```

However when I change the user and do a `git status`, I get the following error:

```
fatal: Unable to create '.git/index.lock': Permission denied
```

Is this supposed to happen? I access the repo on my local file-system and not via SSH.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Apparently, `--shared={all|world|everybody}` is broken in recent Git. Use octal permissions:

```
git init --shared=0777
```

Comment: Lars, when I try to do a commit as another user, this is the error message I get: **fatal: could not open '.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG': Permission denied** So I doubt that did the trick. I've changed my files to CHMOD 777, so the permissions to the file is not a problem ...

Comment: I have same problem, even after _git init --shared=0777_. Any solutions?

Comment: you might have to create a `bare` repository: `git --bare init --shared=0777`

Answer (score 3):

you need to specify in the shared option which group of users you want to share with. http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-init.html

you also need to make sure all the users you want to share with are in the same group.

Comment: Can't I make it accessible to all? Do I NEED to make it accessible to a group?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can try to avoid setting the permission level to 777,

```
change the ownership
sudo chown -v -R username:groupname sprout
chmod -R g+w .git/*
```